# Very slow loading of keystore file (javax.net.ssl.keyStore property)

Tags: java

The loading of keystore file (set by "javax.net.ssl.keyStore" property) is very slow. It takes around 8 seconds to load a custom keystore file.

Considering a client app in Java that has its total load time affected, is there any workaround to speedup this?

**EDIT - Environment characteristics:**

- AIX 7.1 (there is not virus scanner)
- Java 8
- JFS2 (Filesystem)
- The keystore has around 160 entries

Comment: Usually it does not take that long, something is special with the file or your system. How many entries are in your custom keystore file? Is there a virus scanner or something similar that could delay the file access?

Comment: @Robert I've edited the question putting there more info about the environment.

Comment: I would try to load the keystore on a regular PC using a common Java version. If this works the problem is most likely located in the Java runtime you use (what Java is used on an AIX system?). If this is the case contact you Java vendor for support.

Comment: @Robert: We have already tried to do that in a clean (lightweight) Linux environment running Java 10 and it's still slow.

Comment: @Robert: It seems that Java "keystore engine" is checking every CA certificate, inclusive their signatures. We can see that procedure happening slowly through the debug output of Java VM, it really takes a lot of time. I wonder if there isn't a way to turn off that checking and just trust on them, since it's an already trusted keystore and protected by a password.

Comment: `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` seems to be a class/package/property name, not an actual file. Are you referring to a .jks/.p12 file? If it is a keystore containing certificates, make sure that the certificates have complete CA-chain, not only the EE-certificate.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond "javax.net.ssl.keyStore" stands for the property that set the keystore file, question was edited to make it clearer. What is "EE-certificate"? What does this "EE" mean?

Comment: Well EE=EndEntity, the owner of the certificate; for example stackoverflow.com has a certificate from an Intermediate CA, the Intermediate CA has a certificate from a Root CA; and finally the Root CA has a self-signed certificate. The complete chain consist of three certificates: EE's certificate; Intermediate CA's certificate; Root CA's certificate

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond It isn't easy to analyse a keystore file through the `keytool` command line (although assisted by `grep`, `awk`,...). However, I could find 8 certificates who has the object `BasicConstraints` marked as "CA:false", but how can I check if their whole parent chains are (or not) in that keystore file? Why the absence of their parent chain could cause slowness?